# Liferay 6.2 rest api with content type text/xml

Tags: xml, rest, api, liferay, liferay-6.2

I am trying to create a POST API for a client so that they can send XML to my server, the problem is in Liferay I am unable to find how to create such API. As per my findings, Liferay only provides implementation/support for JSON and SOAP services.

Comment: Why don't you integrate Spring into your portlet  here is link http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2012/09/spring-mvc-portlet-in-liferay.html and build rest API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Service API is not directly related with your portlet, you could also host a plain Servlet using [PortalDelegateServlet](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/PortalDelegateServlet.html) [liferay-invoke-servlet-from-portlet.html](http://informatik-hub.blogspot.com/2012/06/liferay-invoke-servlet-from-portlet.html) so that clients can post raw XML to your server, that you can process. Your URL will look like: {HOST}/delegate/{Sub-ContextName}. But you need to take care of authentication/authorization by yourself using principal information.